# Passing IplImage pointers in opencv

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, opencv

I am looking to pass an IplImage* to a function and display the image in that function. My code is as follows.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


IplImage* doPyrDown(IplImage* in) {

    cvNamedWindow( "Debug", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Debug", in );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&in );

    IplImage* out = 0;
    return( out );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    cvNamedWindow( "Example6-in", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    IplImage* imgIN = 0;
    IplImage* imgOUT = 0;

    imgIN = cvLoadImage("image.jpg");
    cvShowImage("Example6-in", imgIN );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgIN );

    imgOUT = doPyrDown(imgIN);

    return 0;
}
```

The original image is displayed in the main function. But the image isn't getting displayed in the doPyrDown function. An empty window is getting created called "Debug".

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove cvReleaseImage line from main function.

Answer (score 1):

You do a `cvReleaseImage` on `imgIN` before passing it into `doPyrDown`. I'm not familiar with opencv but I would not expect cvShowImage to work after that.